# fetching multiple echoes from wamp or xamp server to android textviews by giving server links to multiple textviews

Tags: php, android, server, textview, echo

In my application i have taken two textviews.  I want to retrieve php echo from server by giving link to first textview in android code and similarly for second textview i will give another link.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
        TextView txtView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        //ASYNC WAY
        new GetData(txtView).execute("");
        new GetData(txtView2).execute("");
    }
    private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        private TextView display,display2;
        GetData(TextView view){
            this.display = view;
            this.display2=view;
            display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
            display2=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt2);
        }
        protected String doInBackground(String... message){
            HttpClient httpclient;
            HttpGet request;
            HttpResponse response = null;
            String result = "";
            try{
                httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                request = new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.8:8080/Android_db/receive2.php");
                response = httpclient.execute(request);
            } catch (Exception e){
                result = "error1";
            }
            try{
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()));
                String line="";
                while((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
                    result = result + line;
                }
            } catch(Exception e){
                result = "error2";
            }
            return result;
        }
    enter code here
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            this.display.setText(result);
        }
    }}
```

And in the php file i am simply echoing hello in first textview..how can i view the message from another php file in the second textview? please help.